# How do I get rid of the gray space at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

Scrolling is disabled on this webpage, however, when using an iPad in landscape, this problem occurs. There is no gray space at the bottom until you try to scroll down (this is disabled) but all of the sudden the gray space appears. I've tried to find the answer everywhere with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

seems to be fixing the issue.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you

Comment: Just curious, how did you think/know this would fix the problem? As in, why does this fix the problem? @manolis

Comment: Usually when we have absolute positioned elements inside the `body`, the `body` itself must have `position` specified.

Answer (score 0):

For responsive design, using **padding/margin** sometime causes the issue of overlapping the main design. For this type of problem, it is good practice to not to use **fixed height** or if you need to use it then fix it with margin/padding.
you can fix body position to relative. here, position: relative; 
positioned relative to its normal position.